# There is no applicable constructor

Tags: android

Есть класс SetData папке database относительно main.java. В main.java импортирую  import antonin.juliamusic.database.*;  и пытаюсь создать экземпляр SetData. Выбивает There is no applicable constructor. Есть SetData в той же папке, что и main,  то проблем нет. Что это можеть быть?

Comment: Немного кода, пожалуйста. Как создаете экземпляр и какие конструкторы обьявлены у класса, и т.п.

Comment: Создаю  SetData set = new SetData(); Конструктор пустой SetData(){}

Comment: Полный лог ошибки, пожалуйста. Кто предок `SetData`?

Comment: Это ошибка выбивает сразу до компиляции. Логов там вроде нет. Класс ни от кого не наследуеться

Answer (score 1):

Если класс находится в другом пакете, конструктор должен быть с модификатором `public`

---

> There is no applicable constructor

Значит, что нет применимого конструктора. Если Вы наследуетесь от какого-то класса, в его конструкторе должен быть в первую очередь вызван `super(/*параметры*/);`

Comment: Не наследуюсь. И почему если класс , в котором создается екземпляр и и класс из которого создается в одной папке то все нормально.

Comment: @user186301 с n-го прочтения понял вопрос. Пропишите `public` конструктору.

Comment: Помогло. Спасибо. Может напишите это ответом, что бы отметить правильное решение

Comment: @user186301 Обновил ответ. Старый вариант пусть тоже будет, может кому пригодится.